# Add maximize and minimize button for Jquery Sortable Portlets

Tags: jquery, css

I have used Jquery sortable UI from [Jquery Sortable UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#portlets)

I want to add maximize and minimize button for each widget.When 'maximize' clicked the widget will occupy the whole page and hide other widgets.How to do this.

I have tried to hide all columns and insert a new div with current widget. But I pushed to append the widget once again..So i have confused lot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done exactly this before and after some thinking about it, I found a very easy solution.

You just set the the particular widget to

```
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:100%;
```

Then you have your widget full-screen.
When you set the position (and width and height) back, it goes automatically back to the position where it was before.

Comment: But other widgets will not hide and also i have two coloumns in Layout...I want to remove this columns and make a single column...

Comment: ??? When you set the position to absolute, the particular widget is shown above your other widgets and is out of your columns. You don't need to hide the others or change the columns.